# Mimicking jQuery event.which in GWT

Tags: java, gwt, gwtquery

The GwtQuery documentation provides the following example as a starting point for fiddling with events:

```
$("h1").bind(Event.ONMOUSEOVER | Event.ONMOUSEOUT, new Function() {
  public boolean f(Event e) {
    $(e).toggleClass("highlight");
    return true;
  }
});
```

However, unlike the jQuery parallel, there is no `this` keyword to refer to the element inside the handler, that's why it is passed as `Event e`, to be wrapped within `$()`. But then, we don't have access to the actual event. How do we calculate in GWT what we can in jQuery with `event.which`, or `event.target`?

Specifically, I am looking for two events. One is a `mousedown`, after which I need to check whether it was the left button (jQuery equivalent being `e.which == 1`), and a `keyup` event, after which I need to check for specific keys (`e.keyCode == 13`, etc).

Comment: Remove [tag:gwt], if you are not looking for GWT-related answers. It may be for the best

Comment: Well, `gwtquery` is essentially related to `gwt`, so I think this should be tagged as `gwt` question also..

Comment: What's wrong with ALexander's answer? Isn't the `Event` passed to the `Function` a GWT object?

Comment: What answer? I don't see any answer here..

Comment: AFAIK, GWT cant bind all elements with events as easy as jQuery...(unless you use BodyElement.getElementsByTagName and sinkEvent, which I will never bother to use). You can put JS code in the HTML file anyway so I suggest to use the JS code you have

Comment: Yeah, may be I will try to do that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Event` object passed to the function is the GWT object `com.google.gwt.user.client.Event`
So if you want to know if the left button was pressed :

```
if (e.getButton() == NativeEvent.BUTTON_LEFT){
 ...
}
```

if you want to know which key was pressed:
`e.getCharCode()`